# Issue about Python imaplib library on method append

Tags: python, datetime, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to write an imapsync software that connects on host 1 to account1@host1.com and copy messages and folder to account2@host2.com host2.

Supposing I've already fetched the selected message with his UID with:

```
msg = connection.fetch(idOne, '(RFC822)'))
```

and msg is a good message, below you have the code I've tried to append the message:

```
date = connection.fetch(idOne, '(INTERNALDATE)')[1][0]
date = date.split("\"")[1]
authconnection1.append(folder, "", date, msg)
```

Error is:

```
ValueError: date_time not of a known type
```

I've tried many other possible solutions (with dateutil to convert date string to datetime object, using imaplib.Time2Internaldate I got the same error above ValueError: date_time not of a known type), but no one seems to work. I've searched around the network but nobody seems to have this issue.

Any idea? I'm getting very frustrated of it...

Thank you very much

**Update:**

I've resolved the date_time issue, because the "append" method of imaplib wants that date_time is an integer of seconds, so to retrieve the date I've written this code:

```
# Fetch message from host1
msg = connection.fetch(idOne, '(RFC822)')
# retrieve this message internal date
date = connection.fetch(idOne, '(INTERNALDATE)')[1][0].split("\"")[1]
# Cast str date to datetime object
date = parser.parse(date)
# Removes tzinfo
date = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
# Calculates total seconds between today and the message internal date
date = (datetime.datetime.now()-date).total_seconds()
# Makes the append of the message
authconnection1.append(folder, "", date, msg)
```

But now this fails with error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

So the issue is only changed...

Any ideas?

**Update (RESOLVED):**

imaplib is not working fine, so I've made a workaround for append messages with right date/time. This is my code, I hope it will help everybody:

Function to convert date in right format:

```
def convertDate(date):
    from time import struct_time
    import datetime
    from dateutil import parser

    date = parser.parse(date)
    date = date.timetuple()
    return date
```

Main code:

```
#Get message
msg = authconnection.fetch(idOne, '(RFC822)')
#Get message date
date = authconnection.fetch(idOne, '(INTERNALDATE)')[1][0].split("\"")[1]
#Apply my function I've written above
date = convertDate(date)
#Append message with right date
authconnection1.append(folder, flags, date, msg[1][0][1])
```

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: 2.7, but I was updating this issue.